# How to import module Python files?

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBS7K.png)

file: api_information.py

```
import requests

def OpenProfile():
```

file: Connect_selenium.py

```
from Api.api_automation import OpenProfile
```

However, after running I get the error message:

> from Api.api_automation import OpenProfile
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Api'**

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running `Connect_selenium.py` while in the `Auto_Selenium` directory it will not be able to find the `Api` directory to use as a module. To solve this, you can call `Connect_selenium.py` outside the directory with:

```
$ python3 Auto_Selenium/Connect_selenium.py
```

Also, add an [`__init__.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for) file to the `Api` directory.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you run Conect_selenium.py in the path Autu_selenium will lead this error.

you can run program like this

```
python ./Auto_selenium/Conect_selenium.py
```